# How to display a test coverage result of PHPUnit in eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm using PDT in eclipse to develop PHP application. I add PHPUnit test into the project and it is fully integrated with. Now, I`m looking for a way to adding test coverage check in project. I add the following config for PHPUnit test:

```
<filter>
<whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
<directory suffix=".php">../src</directory>
</whitelist>
</filter>
<logging>
<log type="coverage-clover" target="./clover.xml"/>
</logging>
```

The coverage xml file is generated but it is very hard to explore results.

Is there any plugin to show the result in eclipse view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use the HTML output...

```
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/codeCoverage" charset="UTF-8"
        yui="true" highlight="true"
        lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
</logging>
```

You can open the output in a browser.